# Why am I getting "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException"?

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

Why am I getting "Exception in thread `main`, `java.lang.NullPointerException`? I am getting this exception on line 27 of PizzaDEMO Class. That line reads

```
order[i].addPizza(size, pepperoni, sasuage, mushrooms);
```

The output is:

```
Enter the size s = small m = middom and l = large.
l
If it has pepperoni enter true, if not enter false.
true
If it has sasuage enter true, if not enter false.
true
If it has mushrooms enter true, if not enter false.
true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at PizzaDEMO.main(PizzaDEMO.java:27)

Process completed.
```

Thank you :)

```
 import java.util.*;
class PizzaDEMO 
{
    public static void main(String args [])
    {
        PizzaOrder[] order = new PizzaOrder[3];

        for (int i = 0; i < order.length; i++)
        {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            char size = 'l';
            boolean pepperoni = true;
            boolean sasuage = true;
            boolean mushrooms = true;

            System.out.println("Enter the size s = small m = middom and l = large.");
            size = reader.next().charAt(0);
            System.out.println("If it has pepperoni enter true, if not enter false.");
            pepperoni = scanner.nextBoolean();
            System.out.println("If it has sasuage enter true, if not enter false.");    
            sasuage = scanner.nextBoolean();    
            System.out.println("If it has mushrooms enter true, if not enter false.");  
            mushrooms = scanner.nextBoolean();
            order[i].addPizza(size, pepperoni, sasuage, mushrooms);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i == order.length; i++)
        {   
            System.out.println(order[i].cost());
        }                                   
    }    
}


/*
class PizzaDEMO 
{
    public static void main(String args [])
    {
        PizzaOrder order = new PizzaOrder();

        order.addPizza('l', true, true, true);
        order.addPizza('s', true, true, true);
        order.addPizza('s', true, false, true);
        order.addPizza('m', false, false, false);
        order.addPizza('m', false, true, false);

        System.out.println(order.cost());                               
    }    
}
*/
class PizzaOrder 
{
    private final int MAXPIZZAS = 10;
    private Pizza[] pizzas = new Pizza[MAXPIZZAS];

    int numPizzas = 0;

    public void addPizza(char size,  boolean pepperoni, boolean sasuage, boolean mushrooms)
    {
        if(numPizzas!=MAXPIZZAS)
        {
            pizzas[numPizzas] = new Pizza(size, pepperoni, sasuage, mushrooms);

            numPizzas++;    
        }

    }

    public double cost()
    {
        double total = 0;

        for (int i=0; i<numPizzas;i++)
        {
            if(pizzas[i].getSize()=='s')
                total += 8;

            else if(pizzas[i].getSize()=='m')
                total += 10;

            else if(pizzas[i].getSize()=='l')
                total += 12;

            else
                System.out.println("Not a Size");

            total+= pizzas[i].getNumToppings();                                         
        }
        return total;           
    }   
}
/* Chapter No. 12 - Exercise No. 2    [REQUIRED: otherwise zero points]
   File Name:          Pizza.java
   Programmer:         Jared Wines
   Date Last Modified: Oct. 12, 2013

   Problem Statement: This program with record the cost of the pizza with the size and toppings of the pizza.



   Overall Plan (step-by-step, how you want the code to make it happen):
   1. Make a pizza class with all the constutors and intance varible.
   2. Make a pizza order class that caluates the cost of the pizza.
   3. Make a pizzmdemo that inputs the pizza data than outputs the cost of the pizza.


   Classes needed and Purpose (Input, Processing, Output)
   main class – MyProgram


*/

public class Pizza 
{
        private char size;
        private boolean sasuage;
        private boolean pepperoni;
        private boolean mushrooms;

        public Pizza(char size,  boolean pepperoni, boolean sasuage, boolean mushrooms)
        {
            this.size=size;
            this.pepperoni=pepperoni;
            this.sasuage=sasuage;   
            this.mushrooms=mushrooms;   
        }

        public char getSize()
        {
            return size;
        }   

        public int getNumToppings()
        {
            int count = 0;

            if(pepperoni)
                count++;
            if(sasuage)
                count++;
            if(mushrooms)
                count++ ;

            return count;               
        }       
}
```

Comment: *Why am I getting “Exception in thread ”main“ java.lang.NullPointerException”?* because you're using a variable with `null` value in your application. You can see **where** by reading the stacktrace of the error.

Comment: You didn't instantiate any `PizzaOrder` element in your `order` array.

Answer (score 2):

Because `order[i]` is still `null`. So it tries to execute `null.addPizza(...)`.

You'll need to fill the array with something before trying to execute methods of the elements of the array. Right now it's all `null`. Something like `order[0] = new PizzaOrder();`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are calling the method on a reference that doesn't point to an object.
You have to create a new PizzaOrder object for every order[i] reference.
In the first for loop, just add:

```
order[i] = new PizzaOrder();
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

First you have to enter a pizzaorder object into order array. with out an order it cant add pizza into it. Pizza order object is null in the order[i].

order[i]= new PizzaOrder();
then you can take the Order object and can add pizza into this order

Answer (score 0):

Remember when you create an array of objects in Java, you are given an array of the size you want filled with nulls. None of the objects exist yet. This might be confusing if you are used to dealing with primitives (int, boolean, etc) where you'll get a default value (0 for numerical primitives).

So keeping that in mind, when you hit this line:

```
order[i].addPizza(size, pepperoni, sasuage, mushrooms);
```

You are telling the computer to "find me the object at slot i in the order array". Unfortunately, because that is null, it gives you a null object and you then call `addPizza` on it! This is where your `NullPointerException` is coming from.

The fix is to create each object as you loop through the array. Somewhere around the top of the loop you'll want to do something like this:

```
order[i] = new PizzaOrder();
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

There are several [rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10.1) how array creation expressions are evaluated at runtime. Let us pay attention to this specific step:

> ... a one-dimensional array is created of the specified length, and each component of the array is initialized to its default value (§4.12.5).

But, what is the default value of a reference type? I know you guessed it right. From [§4.12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5) of the java language specification:

> ...
>
> For all reference types (§4.3), the default value is **null**.